# cross server environment variable

Tags: java, tomcat, glassfish, environment-variables

I would like to set to be able to set a string variable such as "DEVEL" or "PRODUCTION", in `Glassfishv3` and `Apache tomcat 6` servers, and want it to be accessible from java code so I can change behaviour of my app according to the variable. What is the easiest way of doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For tomcat you can use `CATALINA_OPTS` environment variable in order to set system properties:

```
CATALINA_OPTS   (Optional) Java runtime options used when the "start",
                or "run" command is executed.
```

So you can setup this in IDE or just in command line:

```
CATALINA_OPTS=-DdevelopmentMode=true
```

And then in your app:

```
System.getProperty("developmentMode")
```

Comment: I eventuelly discovered, that there is System properties tab in glassfish gui admin which creates a variable that is accessible by `System.getProperty`.

Comment: @coubeatczech : you can also set a system property from the command-line.  No need to get all GUI... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907075/cross-server-environment-variable/4910087#4910087

Answer (score 4):

I do not think there is a method of setting an environment variable that works for both of these servers.  There are methods to set an environment variable for each of these servers though.

### To set a system property that can be detected by your web application at run-time:

**Tomcat** : Set the value of the environment variable CATALINA_OPTS and start the server.

```
export CATALINA_OPTS=-DmyPropertyName=myPropertyValue
```

**GlassFish 3** : There are a couple methods that you can use.

1. Direct use of a GlassFish system property.  Start the server. Use the asadmin command 'create-system-properties' to define a System property. Restart the server.

   asadmin create-system-property myPropertyName=myPropertyValue.
2. Direct use of a JVM Option: Start the server. Use the asadmin command 'create-jvm-option' to create a new JVM option that defines the System property that will be used when the server is started.  Restart the server so that it uses the property.

   asadmin create-jvm-options -DmyPropertyName=myPropertyValue

### To change the value of a system property that can be detected by your web application at run-time:

**Tomcat** : Change the value of the CATALINA_OPTS environment variable and restart your server.

```
export CATALINA_OPTS=-DmyPropertyName=myNEWPropertyValue
```

**GlassFish 3** : The method to change the property value depends on the method you used to set the property value.

1. Direct use of a GlassFish system property. Recreate the GlassFish system property with the 'create-system-properties' command and restart the server.

   asadmin create-system-property myPropertyName=myNEWPropertyValue
2. Direct use of a JVM option: Delete the old jvm option and create a new one in its place.  Restart the server.

   asadmin delete-jvm-options -DmyPropertyName=myPropertyValue

   asadmin create-jvm-options -DmyPropertyName=myNEWPropertyValue

   See http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-11253

### To unset the value of a system property that can be detected by your web application at run-time:

**Tomcat** : Reset the value of the environment variable CATALINA_OPTS, without including the JVM Option definition.  Restart the server.

```
export CATALINA_OPTS=
```

**GlassFish 3** :

1. Using a GlassFish system property. Use the 'delete-system-properties' command and restart the server.

   asadmin delete-system-property myPropertyName
2. Using a JVM Option to define the property. Use the delete-jvm-options command and restart the server.

   asadmin delete-jvm-options -DmyPropertyName=myPropertyValue

### To access a system property from inside your web application

Use [System.getProperty(String)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29) or [System.getProperty(String,String)][2]

## After saying all this, I want to discourage you from using this info to pursue your stated development strategy.

There are other methods to differentiate a development and production environment that do not involve code changes.

[2]: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: "... other methods to differentiate ..." and these method are which ones?

Comment: @coubeatczech : You probably want to ask this question as a new question, so a wider number of folks will respond to it.

Comment: could you give me at least some hint, why is this solution worth discouraging? I kind of wouldn't know what would I ask...

Comment: @coubeatczech: Some issues with detecting your environment in an app... You may end up putting code into 'production' that has not been tested... that seems like a bad thing.  Your app, written in Java (an OOP language), will start being 'not OO'... not big deal for a small project, but if it grows to have a team of folks working on it this System property will start to get used poorly if not totally incorrectly. There is also the chance that the System property will get set to some new value... like "Qualifying" and then any and all if statements that involve the property need examination

Answer (score 0):

Use an env-entry in the web.xml :

```
<env-entry>
  <description>development or production</description>
  <env-entry-name>devMode</env-entry-name>
  <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
  <env-entry-value>PRODUCTION</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

And in the Java code, you can do :

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
String devMode = (String) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env/devMode");
```

Comment: but web.xml is in the application, not in the server. I want to set the variable in server...

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether it should be constant or dynamic variable. Whether you want to change it during compilation time or in the runtime on the fly. With 1st approach you may do that in web.xml setting init parameter or env-entries or even use simple property file packed in the jar archive. With the 2nd approach you could use special kind of configuration table in your database which would be pooled by the application piropdically or maybe you could harness JMX management mechanism and modify configuration on the fly using jconsole