# Setting Runtime Property in Web Application

Tags: java, tomcat, glassfish

I am planning to use JGroups in a web application.

JGroups by default uses IPv6 for multicasting of messages.  JGroups can only be configured to use IPv4 by setting a property like the following (see [docs](http://www.jgroups.org/manual/html_single/index.html#d0e523))

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

This does not work if set in code.  What are my options when running a war file in an application server for setting this property, specifically tomcat and glassfish?

Comment: possible duplicate of [cross server environment variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907075/cross-server-environment-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a specific reason to put this in code, it can easily be configured for Tomcat by setting the environment variable CATALINA_OPTS (to -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true). I think the proper place to do this is to create ${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/setenv.sh and place the setting in there.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me the following route might work. First, add a [ServletContextListener](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) to your web app and register it in `web.xml` before JGroups is loaded.

Now, inside the [contextInitialized](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29) method, use `System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true")`.

Disclaimer: not tested.